# mac os x - UNIX domain sockets in abstract namespace

Tags: macos

Are they possible?

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/perl5110delta5.12.1.html) it is possible starting from Mac osx 10.9. Ctrl + F for "New support for Abstract namespace sockets" on that page. But I was not able to find one single example for Mac.

Also in Linux the sockets created in the abstract name space you can see them in /proc/net/unix (cat -v /proc/net/unix).
The mac does not have /proc/...

Where can I expect to find them? Does it have something similar to Linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer documentation linked is for `perl`, not Mac OS X. The documentation states that **perl v5.11.0** is capable of supporting abstract socket namespaces.

The undocumented assumption is that the underlying operating system also provides this support.

I am not aware of any Apple documentation saying Mac OS X supports abstract namespace sockets.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9 included `perl` as a component. I presume these manual pages are installed in the appropriate system `man` file location and were then picked up by Apple's man page to web page tools.